# TikZ: Changing arrow styles when using graphdrawing

Tags: luatex, tikz-arrows, tikz-graphs

I want all arrows in a TikZ drawing to have a larger tip, so I change the `arrows` setting in the `\tikz` options. This works fine for manually created drawings, but doesn't work when generating graphs with one of the layouts from the *graphdrawing* library.

Changing settings for `\draw` doesn't work either, while adding them to `edge` did work for some other options, but not for arrow scaling. (It seems like it can't handle the nested braces.) I assume *graphdrawing* has to explicitly overwrite arrow styles in order to do its magic, but how am I to supposed to customize things?

### Minimal example

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}

\tikz[simple necklace layout, nodes={draw, circle}, node distance=5cm,
      arrows={-Stealth[scale=2]}] {
    \node (1) {Node 1};
    \node (2) {Node 2};

    \draw (1) edge (2);
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Actual (unexpected) result]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `>={Stealth[scale=2]` as an option of the `tikz` command together with `edge[->]`:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}
\tikz[simple necklace layout, nodes={draw, circle}, node distance=5cm,
  >={Stealth[scale=2]}
]{
  \node (1) {Node 1};
  \node (2) {Node 2};
  \draw (1) edge[->] (2);
}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or you can load the tikzlibrary `graphs` and use the `\graph` command:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}
\tikz[simple necklace layout, nodes={draw, circle}, node distance=5cm,
  >={Stealth[scale=2]}
]{
  \node (1) {Node 1};
  \node (2) {Node 2};
  \graph {
    (1) -> (2);
  };
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your first solution mostly matches my requirements, I'll go with it.